# Problem with REST setBody while posting to an external service

Tags: apex, rest-api, json

I have a Json function **generateBody** that output as JSON.

```
 String requestbody = generateBody(caseids);
```

The debug log for **requestbody**  outputs as:

```
{"Cases" : [ {
"short_description" : "Test Text"
} ]
}
```

When I pass to setBody...

```
 req.setBody(requestbody);
```

I get blank field as response. But when I hardcod it, it works. Following is the way I did...

```
String postData = '{\"short_description\":\"Posting a test Text\"}';
req.setBody(postData);
```

Function is...

```
   public static String generateBody(set<id> casesids)
   {
   JSONGenerator gen = JSON.createGenerator(true);
   gen.writeStartObject();
   gen.writeFieldName('Cases');
   gen.writeStartArray();
   gen.writeStartObject();             
   for(Case c : [Select Id, RecordTypeId, RecordType.Name, Subject From Case Where Id IN : casesids]) {
     if(c.RecordType.Name == 'Incident'){
       //define different fields which you want to pass.

       gen.writeStringField('short_description',c.Subject);
       gen.writeEndObject(); 
      } 

    }  
       gen.writeEndArray();
       gen.writeEndObject();
```

Is there anything that I missed? I can post the whole method if required.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: are you still fighting with this issue. :) lets chat again.

Comment: Are you setting header? request.setHeader('Content-type','Application/json');.  Your json seems invalid to me

Comment: yep @Himanshu. Yes susanoo. already set

Comment: your hard coded example is different (it doesn't have the nested array in it)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your `generateBody` is creating invalid JSON. It should be an object or an array at the top level. Looks like it is missing the outermost set of curly braces.

Comment: function added..

Comment: that is generating correct one. he missed initial curly braces while posting the code.

Comment: @Himanshu This is a follow-up from the prev code we discussed.

Comment: yes i know. let's discuss in that. http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/31500/discussion-between-himanshu-and-mnz

Comment: let me know what should I do with this question. Moving on to the chat....

Comment: Removing gen.writeFieldName('Cases'); gen.writeStartArray(); and gen.writeEndArray(); did the trick as it was generating an unwanted format format